# Click a Button to Move through List of Webpages

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I am creating a profile centered website.

I have a webpage that has fixed side buttons (SKIP and ADD). I know that I may need to create an array for all the webpages/profiles but... How do I start the process for the SKIP and ADD buttons to cycle to the NEXT profile in the list/array? Both the SKIP and ADD buttons move to the NEXT profile. However, a small notice appears when you click ADD to move forward.

I do have programming experience and have my AWS and Linux certifications. I'm not worried about following along! Please help. Any and all assistance is so greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking, but you could store an index for the current profile and increment when you click the skip or add button. The current profile would be `array[index]`

Answer (score 0):

You weren't detailed enough in your question so that's the skeleton to handle a cursor for a list. A cursor that will be moved and processed by the add() and skip() functions called by the click events of the buttons Add and Skip. The div#currentItem holds the value of the current item in the list. Every time you press the Skip button, the cursor will move to the next item showing it's value on the div above said. Ever ytime you press the Add button, the function add() will be invoked:

```
<div id="currentItem">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="skip();">Skip</button>
<input type="button" onclick="add();">Add</button>

<script>

  var list = [];
  var cursor = 0;

  $(document).ready({
    init();
  });

  function init(){
    //feed here list var somehow
    showCurrentItem();
  }

  function showCurrentItem(){
    $('#currentItem').text( list[cursor] );
  }

  function skip(){
    cursor++;
    showCurrentItem();
  }

  function add(){
    let currentItem = list[i];
    //do something with currentItem
  }
</script>
```